# Android SurfaceView overlay on camera view does not show when preview is on

Tags: java, android, camera, overlay, surfaceview

I have a FrameLayout containing two SurfaceViews. One of them will show the camera preview, and the other is a custom surface view I use for drawing. Problem is the surface view does not show up. If I comment out the line where the camera starts preview, it does though, on the black background. This indicates me that the Surface view is positioned well, but I suspect that when the camera preview draws, something goes wrong.

The camera view:

```
public CameraView(Context context, AttributeSet a) {
    super(context, a);
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}
```

The custom view:

```
public InclinaisonGauge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    run = true;
    updateThread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            Canvas c = null;
            final SurfaceHolder inclHolder = getHolder();
            while (run) {
                try {
                    c = inclHolder.lockCanvas();
                    if(c!=null)
                    {
                        synchronized (inclHolder) {
                            onDraw(c);
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (c != null) {
                    inclHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }           
        }
    }
};
```

And I use this very simple draw method on the custom view to make sure it is not a framerate issue

```
public void doDraw(final Canvas canvas, final boolean bigSize, float daDirection)
{
    canvas.drawARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
}
```

Has anyone experienced this?

Thanks

Comment: Here is a simple project showing the problem - http://dl.free.fr/f4rt18a1o . Start it and you will only see the camera. In CameraView, comment out the line where it starts preview and you will see the SurfaceView being drawn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, if anyone else gets this, solution is to call this on the surfaceView

```
this.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think SurfaceViews are intended to be used as an overlay, but it is possible to achieve this behavior. What you have to do is when the SurfaceView class is created:

```
    setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
    getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: This was the solution for me. setZOrderMediaOverlay was not sufficient. I believe this should have been the accepted answer